# How to make a moving picture go off the screen and make it come back again

Tags: java, processing

I am new to processing and I am creating this small game where these stick men try to avoid the attacker. I have added a moving stick man. It goes from bottom to top, but when it reaches the top, it doesn't come back up from the bottom side again, it just disappears. I was wondering what I could do to make this change. [Picture for the stick man moving up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ0Z9.png) [This is what happens when the stick man go off the screen they don't return back from the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqe5r.png)

```
void setup()
{
  size(800,400);
  stick2 = new Stick(10, 200, 2);
  stick3 = new Stick(150,200, 3);
}

void draw()
{
  background(240);
  stick2.render();
  stick2.move();
  stick3.render();
  stick3.move();
}
```

```
class Stick
{
 //members?
 int x, y;
 int speedX = 2;
 int speedY = 2;
 int animationcounter = 0; //animation
 PImage img1, img2;
  
 //constructor - load images
 Stick(int x, int y, int speed)
 {
   
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.speedX = speed; 
   img1 = loadImage("stick1.png");//loads from .pde source code directory
   img2 = loadImage("stick2.png");

 }
  void render()
 {
   //cycle through images, and back to image1
   
   if (animationcounter >0 & animationcounter <=8)
    { image(img1,this.x,this.y); }
     else if (animationcounter >8 & animationcounter <=20)
    {image(img2,this.x,this.y);  }
    
    else
    {
    image(img2,this.x,this.y);
    }
    
    animationcounter = animationcounter+1;
    if (animationcounter>32)
      animationcounter = 0;
 }
 void move()
 {
   this.y = this.y - speedY; //move rightwards
   if (this.y>height)
     this.y = +img1.height;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're not actually checking if the stickman goes above the screen.
You're checking if its y value is higher than height, in other words, if it's *below* the screen.

[image: Example of the coordinates on screen]

Also, it would be nice if the image goes completely off the screen before it appears on the other side.
To achieve this, your move function should look like this

```java
void move()
{
   this.y = this.y - speedY;

   //image goes above the screen
   if (this.y < 0 - img1.height) //subtract the image height so the image completely disappears before it moves down
     this.y = height + img1.height;
   //image goes below the screen
   if (this.y > height + img1.height)
     this.y = -img1.height;
 }
```